# Oracle 10g forms builder has stopped working

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Oracle 10g forms builder has stopped working on Windows 7 Enterprise while opening an existing .fmb file, which was made in same environment.

The user is trying to open an existing form with extension ‘.fmb’ after connecting the form builder application to the oracle database, at that time only the application is showing ‘stopped working’ message. Those forms has been given by DBA team to user. And user needs to modify on those forms. I tried with multiple forms to open through the application, most of them causes the same message to appear and the application is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing much I can suggest that will fix your problems quickly. Anyway, here's what I think: you (or, even better, administrators) should check whether Forms version you use is/was supported & certified with operating system you use.

I have Forms 10g, ver. 9.0.4 (it was the very first 10g version, regardless the "9.x" version number) which was supported on Windows XP. That's why I installed virtual machine on my computer, put XP onto it and installed Forms. Everything works just fine.

Now, if it turns out that you're running a combination of Oracle software and operating system that wasn't certified (i.e. there's no guarantee that it'll work), I suggest you do the same. It will take some time to make it up and running (matter of an hour or two), but then you can share that virtual machine among all the developers, without any new installation.

Certification matrix is available at My Oracle Support (MOS); have a look. Also, MOS might even have a solution (patch?) for your problems - search their database.

Answer (score -1):

Stuck in this exact problem and unable to find a fix to this.

I create a form from TEMPLATE.fmb on my Windows 7 64bit machine using Forms [32 Bit] Version 10.1.2.0.2.
The form is created successfully. Then I transfer the fmb to AU_TOP forms folder and compile it using frmcmp_batch, No error. The form is compiled and running.

Now when I transfer that same FMB from AU_TOP to my machine and reopen in form builder, it crashes.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe3WW.png)

Comment: Please provide concrete answers to questions. Stating that you also struggle with the same problem is not a valid response!